# Using All in MapAt in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I often have a list of pairs, as

```
data = {{0,0.0},{1,12.4},{2,14.6},{3,25.1}}
```

and I want to do something, for instance `Rescale`, to all of the second elements without touching the first elements. The neatest way I know is:

```
Transpose[MapAt[Rescale, Transpose[data], 2]]
```

There must be a way to do this without so much `Transpose`ing. My wish is for something like this to work:

```
MapAt[Rescale, data, {All, 2}]
```

But my understanding is that `MapAt` takes `Position`-style specifications instead of `Part`-style specifications. What's the proper solution?

#### To clarify,

I'm seeking a solution where I don't have to repeat myself, so lacking double `Transpose` or double `[[All,2]]`, because I consider repetition a signal I'm not doing something the easiest way. However, if eliminating the repetition requires the introduction of intermediate variables or a named function or other additional complexity, maybe the transpose/untranspose solution is already correct.

Comment: Note that `[[All,2]]` has the same number of characters as `Transpose`. So far the solutions are interesting, but I think none is shorter than the double-transpose one, especially if you permit the esc-tr-esc shortcut. Perhaps I should have posed the question as a code golf challenge?

Comment: if you want a shorter solution you probably should specifically ask for it. different people will consider different things to be the (proper OR most elegant OR easiest to understand) solution.

Comment: Well if you simply don't want a double `Transpose` or double `[[All,2]]`, both answers I gave seem suitable :) (I'd go for Mr.W's though, it's easier to read if not to write)

Comment: Why is you data that form on the first place, {{_Integer,_Real},..} performance wise {{__Integer},{__Real}} where better and then you would not have the problem to begin with.

Comment: Thanks, all, for your answers. There is not always a super-compact way to do these things; these solutions have shown the variety that is possible when seeking a balance between compactness and versatility.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Part.html):

```
data = {{0, 0.0}, {1, 12.4}, {2, 14.6}, {3, 25.1}}

data[[All, 2]] = Rescale @ data[[All, 2]];

data
```

Create a copy first if you need to.  (`data2 = data` then `data2[[All, 2]]` etc.)

---

Amending my answer to keep up with ruebenko's, this can be made into a function also:

```
partReplace[dat_, func_, spec__] :=
  Module[{a = dat},
    a[[spec]] = func @ a[[spec]];
    a
  ]

partReplace[data, Rescale, All, 2]
```

This is quite general is design.

Comment: Putting it in your own words, +1 for doing it exactly the way I'd do it (but see my answer below for a few minor differences)

Answer (score 5):

I am coming late to the party, and what I will describe will differ very little with what @Mr. Wizard has, so it is best to consider this answer as a complementary to his solution. My partial excuses are that first, the function below packages things a bit differently and closer to the syntax of `MapAt` itself, second, it is a bit more general and has an option to use with `Listable` function, and third, I am reproducing my solution from the past [Mathgroup thread](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/browse_thread/thread/f422175a45f13269) for exactly this question, which is more than 2 years old, so I am not plagiarizing :)

So, here is the function:

```
ClearAll[mapAt,MappedListable]; 
Protect[MappedListable]; 
Options[mapAt] = {MappedListable -> False}; 
mapAt[f_, expr_, {pseq : (All | _Integer) ..}, OptionsPattern[]] := 
  Module[{copy = expr}, 
    copy[[pseq]] = 
      If[TrueQ[OptionValue[MappedListable]] && Head[expr] === List, 
        f[copy[[pseq]]], 
        f /@ copy[[pseq]] 
      ]; 
    copy]; 
mapAt[f_, expr_, poslist_List] := MapAt[f, expr, poslist];
```

This is the same idea as what @Mr. Wizard used, with these differences: 1. In case when the spec is not of the prescribed form, regular `MapAt` will be used automatically 2. Not all functions are `Listable`. The solution of @Mr.Wizard assumes that either a function is `Listable` or we want to apply it to the entire list. In the above code, you can specify this by the `MappedListable` option.

I will also borrow a few examples from my answer in the above-mentioned thread:

```
In[18]:= mat=ConstantArray[1,{5,3}];

In[19]:= mapAt[#/10&,mat,{All,3}]
Out[19]= {{1,1,1/10},{1,1,1/10},{1,1,1/10},{1,1,1/10},{1,1,1/10}}

In[20]:= mapAt[#/10&,mat,{3,All}]
Out[20]= {{1,1,1},{1,1,1},{1/10,1/10,1/10},{1,1,1},{1,1,1}}
```

Testing on large lists shows that using Listability improves the performance, although not so dramatically here:

```
In[28]:= largemat=ConstantArray[1,{150000,15}];

In[29]:= mapAt[#/10&,largemat,{All,3}];//Timing
Out[29]= {0.203,Null}

In[30]:= mapAt[#/10&,largemat,{All,3},MappedListable->True];//Timing
Out[30]= {0.094,Null}
```

This is likely because for the above function (`#/10&`), `Map` (which is used internally in `mapAt` for the `MappedListable->False` (default) setting, was able to auto-compile. In the example below, the difference is more substantial:

```
ClearAll[f];
f[x_] := 2 x - 1;

In[54]:= mapAt[f,largemat,{All,3}];//Timing
Out[54]= {0.219,Null}

In[55]:= mapAt[f,largemat,{All,3},MappedListable->True];//Timing
Out[55]= {0.031,Null}
```

The point is that, while `f` was *not* declared `Listable`, *we know* that its body is built out of `Listable` functions, and thus it can be applied to the entire list - but OTOH it can not be auto-compiled by `Map`. Note that adding `Listable` attribute to `f` would have been completely wrong here and would destroy the purpose, leading to `mapAt` being slow in both cases.

Comment: How can I not vote for this?  You always bring a deeper analysis to the table.  By the way, "The solution of @Mr.Wizard assumes that either a function is Listable or we *want to apply it to the entire list*."  I thought that was the point of this question based on the example.  Yours in certainly an interesting take on it.  Your last paragraph highlights something I have wondered about before:  is there, or does it make sense to have, some way to assert that a function as "inherently listable"?  This could help with [misuse case 4 here.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5838577/618728).

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I think one can implement something like the type-inference for Listability, to address this problem. This does not even sound as a very hard problem.

Comment: What do you have in mind?  It is a very loosely formed idea for me at this time.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard The question can be formulated as follows: given a piece of code representing a function call, determine whether or not the result will be *internally* parallelized by appropriate `Listable` kernel functions which are called during the evaluation of this piece of code. But I start to see that this is not such a simple problem as I initially thought, so I  withdraw my previous statement.

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
Transpose[{#[[All, 1]], Rescale[#[[All, 2]]]} &@data]
```

which returns what you want (ie, it does not alter `data`)

If no `Transpose` is allowed,

```
Thread[Join[{#[[All, 1]], Rescale[#[[All, 2]]]} &@data]]
```

works.

EDIT: As "shortest" is now the goal, best from me so far is:

```
data\[LeftDoubleBracket]All, 2\[RightDoubleBracket] = Rescale[data[[All, 2]]]
```

at 80 characters, which is identical to Mr.Wizard's... So vote for [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8580220/559318).

Comment: Is that any cleaner than what he uses now?

Comment: @Mr.W well, obviously I think it is (it uses indexing rather than `MapAt`, transposing and indexing to locate the elements to be acted upon, don't you think this is cleaner?), but of course different people think in different ways.

Comment: Pardon me, I didn't mean to be rude.  I guess I fixated on the OP's request to "do this without so much `Transpose`ing."

Comment: @Mr.W no rudeness perceived. I agree that yours looks cleaner; less @&# going on, which is bizarre :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach:

```
op[data_List, fun_] := 
 Join[data[[All, {1}]], fun[data[[All, {2}]]], 2]

op[data, Rescale]
```

**Edit 1**:

An extension from Mr.Wizard, that does not copy it's data.

```
SetAttributes[partReplace, HoldFirst]
partReplace[dat_, func_, spec__] := dat[[spec]] = func[dat[[spec]]];
```

used like this

```
partReplace[data, Rescale, All, 2]
```

**Edit 2**:
Or like this

```
ReplacePart[data, {All, 2} -> Rescale[data[[All, 2]]]]
```

Comment: `ReplacePart` was the first thing I thought of, but I used `{_, 2}` and it failed.  EDIT:  Oh darn, it still doesn't work. :-((  Is this a v8 change?

Comment: This works in 801 and 804. I don't have V7 handy anymore. It could be that this was fixed, but I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me and a friend

```
In[128]:= m = {{x, sss, x}, {y, sss, y}}
Out[128]= {{2, sss, 2}, {y, sss, y}}

In[129]:= function[ins1_] := ToUpperCase[ins1];
fatmap[ins2_] := MapAt[function, ins2, 2];

In[131]:= Map[fatmap, m]
Out[131]= {{2, ToUpperCase[sss], 2}, {y, ToUpperCase[sss], y}}
```