# Do operations for the second component of each element in a list in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I can use the following way to do some operation (in this case `ToString`) for the first component of each element in a list:

```
{ToString@#[[1]], Rest@#}~Flatten~1 & /@ {{1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}}
```

However, I have a few questions:

- It does not work for `{ToString@#[[1]], Rest@#}~Flatten~1 & /@ {{1,
  2}, 2, {3, 4, 5}}` for obvious reason. How to make it also work in
  this case? The expected output would be `{{"1", 2}, 2, {"3", 4, 5}}`.
- How to do this for the second(or third, etc.) component **easily**? I.e. I want the output to be `{{0}, {1, "2"}, {3, "4", 5}, {6, "7", 9, 10}}`
- Is there a way to use pattern/rule (like
  `/.{#[[1]]->ToString[#[[1]]]}`) for this kind of operation? So please list all solutions you may think of regardless of the efficiency.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8580113/using-all-in-mapat-in-mathematica/. I was initially considering this one as a duplicate of that, but it is not, since it asks about ragged and irregular lists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I didn't realize this was the same as Leonid's core function until I had written it.  Still perhaps that says that this may be a little more transparent than his rather elaborate function.

```
lst = {{1, 2}, 2, {3, 4, 5}};

Replace[lst, {a_, b__} :> {ToString@a, b}, 1]
```

```
{{"1", 2}, 2, {"3", 4, 5}}
```

One can then use `{x:Repeated[_, {4}], a_, b__} :> {x, ToString@a, b}, 1]` for the fifth index, etc.

Comment: I choose this answer because its simplicity and ease to understand. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

The following function should basically do what you want:

```
ClearAll[applyToAll];
applyToAll[f_, list_List, n_Integer] :=
   applyToAll[x_ :> f[x], list, n];
applyToAll[rule : (_Rule | _RuleDelayed), list_List, n_Integer] :=
  Replace[
      list, {left : Repeated[_, {n - 1}], el_, rest___} :> 
        {left, el /. rule, rest}, {1}];
```

and can accept rules. For example:

```
In[192]:= 
applyToAll[ToString, {{1,2},2,{3,4,5}},1]//InputForm
Out[192]//InputForm=  {{"1", 2}, 2, {"3", 4, 5}}

In[193]:= applyToAll[ToString,{{0},{1,2},{3,4,5},{6,7,9,10}},2]//InputForm
Out[193]//InputForm=  {{0}, {1, "2"}, {3, "4", 5}, {6, "7", 9, 10}}

In[194]:= applyToAll[x_?OddQ:>ToString[x],{{0},{1,2},{3,4,5},{6,7,9,10}},2]//InputForm
Out[194]//InputForm= {{0}, {1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}, {6, "7", 9, 10}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another convenient method might be to use `ReplacePart`together with `RuleDelayed`

For example, to turn part 3 of each sublist (if it exists) into a string:

```
ReplacePart[#, 3 :>  ToString@#[[3]]] & /@ {{1, 2}, 
   2, {3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 9, 10}} // InputForm
```

gives as output:

> {{1, 2}, 2, {3, 4, "5"}, {6, 7, "9", 10}}

Similarly, to turn part 1 of  each sublist into a string:

```
ReplacePart[#, 1 :>  ToString@#[[1]]] & /@ {{1, 2}, 
   2, {3, 4, 5}} // InputForm
```

giving:

> {{"1", 2}, 2, {"3", 4, 5}}

Answer (score 1):

In the long run I think that this might be an easier approach, even if it is not exactly what you requested:

```
rep[f_, pos_][x_List] := MapAt[f, x, pos]
rep[__][x_] := x

lst = {{1, 2}, 2, {3, 4, 5}};

rep[ToString, 2] /@ lst
```

```
{{1, "2"}, 2, {3, "4", 5}}
```

You can add arbitrary patterns and conditions to the definition of `rep` as needed.